# apple ipad / ipod lightning connector dock

Tags: ipod, ipad

I am developing a product that needs to plug a dock in to the lightning connector of current ipads and ipods.

The dock needs to simultaneously pass a charge to the device and monitor the activity status of that device, i.e., if it is in sleep or active mode.

Do you think this is possible?  And if so, could it then have the ability to dictate the mode to "force" the device into active or sleep / lock mode?

Comment: Have you asked Apple?  I don't think you're going to get very far with this unless you are a member of their MFI (made for iPod) program.

Comment: There is an assumption here that a reader would know what a "lightning connector" on an iDevice is. Please expand on that, in more generic, electronics terms.

Answer (score 2):

"Lightning" is Apple's proprietary connector. There is a cryptographic transaction between the dock and the device, so you need to sign up to Apple's licensing programme to build devices that interoperate with Apple devices.

References:

- [article about Lightning](http://arstechnica.com/apple/2012/10/apple-revising-mfi-program-to-limit-third-party-lightning-accessories/)
- [Apple manufacturer licensing](http://mfi.apple.com/faqs)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am aware of their program and will certainly apply for it at the right time.  For now, I am needing to know if those functions would at least be possible technically.  Thanks again, though, for your reply.